# R writing functions

Tags: r, function

I want to write a mathematical formula as functions in R.
My formula V(C) = 1/1 + (C / H) ^ n where C, H and n are the parameter of the function that I can change. This is  my first attempts to write a function in R, so please help.

Comment: Are you really computing `1/1`? I might be wrong but it seems you are missing a parenthesis in the denominator. Maybe `1/(1 + C / H)^n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
V <- function( C, H, n ){
  1 / 1 + ( C / H )^n 
}
```