# R pdf function use

Tags: r, pdf

I have me code it work fine.I want to save the obtained histogram in pdf format using the pdf () function:

```
    par(mfrow=c(5,1), mar = c(2,0,2,0),oma = c(1,5,0,0))
   
    x <- rnorm(100,0,1)
    x1 <- rnorm(100, 50,1)
    
    y <- hist(x,plot=FALSE,breaks = 20)
    y1 <- hist(x1, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)
    
    
    base_plot_fun <- function(x, x1, y, y1) {
      mean_x <- mean(x)
      mean_x1 <- mean(x1)
      
      plot(
        0,
        0,
        ylim = range(c(y$counts, y1$counts)),
        xlim = range(c(y$breaks, y1$breaks)),
        xlab = "x",
        ylab = "counts",
        type = "n"
      )
      
      
      corners <- par('usr') # get the corners of the plots
      
      x_left <- corners[1]
      x_right <- quantile(x, 0.95) # at 95 percentile, change as needed
      
      x1_left <- x_right
      x1_right <- quantile(x1, 0.05) # at 5th percentile, change if needed
      
      rect(
        xleft = x_left,
        xright = x_right,
        ybottom = corners[3],
        ytop = corners[4],
        col = 'lightblue',
        density = 100
      )
      rect(
        xleft = x1_left,
        xright = x1_right,
        ybottom = corners[3],
        ytop = corners[4],
        col = 'pink',
        density = 100
      )
    }
    
    base_plot_fun(x = x, x1 = x1, y = y, y1 = y1)
    
    corners <- par('usr') # get the corners of the plots
    
    mean_x <- mean(x)
    mean_x1 <- mean(x1)
    
    x_left <- corners[1]
    x_right <- quantile(x, 0.95) # at 95 percentile, change as needed
    
    x1_left <- x_right
    x1_right <- quantile(x1, 0.05) # at 5th percentile, change if needed
    
    plot(y, col='lightgray',add=TRUE)
    plot(y1, col='gray48',add=TRUE)
    
    
    abline(v=mean_x,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
    abline(v=mean_x1,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
    
    
    abline(v=x_right,col='steelblue',lwd=3)
    abline(v=x1_right,col='firebrick',lwd=3)
    
    
    V <- function( C, H, n ){
      1 / 1 + ( C / H )^n 
    }
    
    V_10 <- V(10,1,0.5)
    x3 <- rnorm(100,V_10,1)
    y3 <- hist(x3, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)
    base_plot_fun(x = x, x1 = x1, y = y, y1 = y1)
    plot(y3, col='gray48',add=T)
    mean_x3 <- mean(x3)
    abline(v=mean_x3,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
    
    V_50 <- V(50,1,0.5)
    x4 <- rnorm(100,V_50,1)
    y4 <- hist(x4, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)
    base_plot_fun(x = x, x1 = x1, y = y, y1 = y1)
    plot(y4, col='gray48',add=T)
    mean_x4 <- mean(x4)
    abline(v=mean_x4,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
    
 
    V_2500 <- V(2500,1,0.1)
    x8 <- rnorm(100,V_2500,1)
    y8<- hist(x8, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)
    base_plot_fun(x = x, x1 = x1, y = y, y1 = y1)
    plot(y8, col='gray48',add=T)
    mean_x8 <- mean(x8)
    abline(v=mean_x8,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
```

I try to use pdf() function in R to save my plots but for same rase it don't work. I try to use code from this side https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/saving-plots-to-a-file-with-pdf-jpeg-and-png.html .Please help in writing pdf () code to save my charts

Comment: I don't see it in your code. What did you try? Run something like `pdf("quiz.pdf")` before your first graphics command (`par(..)` here), then after your last plotting command (`abline(..)`?) call `dev.off()`. After that you can view the pdf.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for not being too precise. In my question, I gave my code to the version where it works. I tried to do what you write in the comment, but then there were errors. So I gave the last one where it worked, but without pdf ()

Comment: Now after I rest my pc its help thanks you agin.

Comment: I [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74374637/r-writing-functions#comment131300563_74374637) don't understand why in your function `V(C, H, n)` you divide `1/1`.

Comment: This is the formula I have to use

Comment: Daisy, are you sure it isn't `1 / (1 + ( C / H )^n)`? The parens completely change it. I'll add my vote to the head-scratch-crowd on any textbook or process that requires you to use `1/1` as a constant in a formula. Order of operations matters. Regardless, have you validated that your `V` function delivers the same results as from the source or a reliable party?

Comment: Daisy, are you attempting to implement the [Hill function](http://www.bio-physics.at/wiki/index.php?title=Hill_Function)? In that reference, it _clearly_ shows `Beta_max` as the sole numerator, and all of `1 + (X * K)^n` in the denominator. In your `V` function, you have one numerator, `1` (constant `Beta_max`, which is fine), and one denominator `1` (constant). And then you multiply that by the ratio to a power. I won't pressure you any more, but if that is the function you're trying to implement, your results are highly unlikely to be even close to correct.

Comment: @r2evans I saw someone else using that same formula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74389457/r-writing-a-mathematical-formula-as-a-function-in-r) and I feel like I've seen more recently too. I wonder where it's coming from.

Comment: Yes, I saw that same question, with the same (alleged?) mistake. I wonder what tutorial/class is teaching that, and how it has not clearly addressed operator precedence as an important point here. Or perhaps the current chapter/topic is intended to include that as a key learning point after hours of frustration. @MrFlick

Comment: @r2evans Here's another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74404450/r-writing-new-function :)

Comment: @r2evans haha. And another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74433826/r-using-curve-function (but at least the parenthesis are correct now).

Comment: @MrFlick, we've now evolved from _writing_ the function to _using_ it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74489825/3358272

Comment: @r2evans Love to see some progress. I saw this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74480197/r-add-to-the-for-loop