# R using curve function

Tags: r, plot

I have my funcion :

```
fun1 <- function( x, y, z ){
  1 / (1 + (x / y)^z) 
}
```

I want to crate `curve` for my function

On X axxis I want values I will give for x, e.g. 10 50, 1000 in my function for Y axis I want fun1 results given different x. For y in function I wants the value 1 and for z I want 0.5 always regardless of the given x.

I try to emulate this code  from the site https://r-charts.com/evolution/curve/

```
# Function
fun <- function(x) {
  sin(sqrt(x ^ 2))
}

# Plot
curve(fun, from = -7, to = 7)
```

Comment: Please be more specific on what you want.  The first example is quite different from the second.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to create a curve for my function fun1 and this other code is an example from the page I try to follow

Comment: repeated? On X axxis I want values I will give for x, e.g. 10 50, 1000 in my function for Y axis I want fun1 results given different x. For  y in function i wants the value 1 and for z I want 0.5 always regardless of the given x. I hope that clears the question

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity this is just the beginning for me in R and on this forum

Comment: I hope I corrected the question well

Comment: What does 10 50, 1000 mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define your function with a single argument, `x`:

```
fun1 <- function( x){
   1 / (1 + (x / 1)^.5) 
}
curve(fun1, from=10, to=1000, n=101)
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

If `fun1` is defined as in the question then we can use the following. It was unclear what domain you want to use.  There we three numbers mentioned in the question 10, 50, 1000 so we used the interval from 10 to 50 as the domain of x but you can easily change that if you want a different domain.

```
curve(fun1(x, y = 1, z = 0.5), from = 10, to = 50)
```

[image: screenshot]