# R add to the for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have my code:

```
V_max=10
V_min=0
H=1
n=1
x_right <- 3.2
x1_right <- 11.8
par(mfrow=c(length(C)+1,1), mar = c(2,0,2,0),oma = c(1,5,0,0))


V <- function( C, H, n ){
  1 / (1 + (C / H)^n) 
}

x_lim_min=-1
x_lim_max=13



C=c(0,0.01,0.1,1)

mylist <- list()
for(i in 1:length(C)){
  V_C <- V_max*V(C[i],H,n)
  x3 <- rnorm(100,V_C,1)
  mylist[i] <- mean(x3)
  y3 <- hist(x3, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)
  maans_to_hist <- unlist(mylist)
  plot(y3, col='gray48',xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max))
}
```

I want to improve my code so that it calculates for all iterations of my for  loop the percentage of my observations in histograms  that are

1. less than `x_right` as one factor and
2. less than `x1_right` but more than `x_right` as second factor

and recorded the results in 2 lists, one for each factor. Honestly, I have no idea how to do it, so I am asking experienced forum users for help

Comment: Thank you for the corection DaveArmstrong it is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that because R is vectorized you can usually avoid using explicit loops altogether.  And you also do not need to define a function for `V`  E.g.:

```
V_max=10
V_min=0
H=1
n=1
x_right <- 3.2
x1_right <- 11.8
par(mfrow=c(length(C)+1,1), mar = c(2,0,2,0),oma = c(1,5,0,0))

C=c(0,0.01,0.1,1)
len_C <- length(C)
x_lim_min=-1
x_lim_max=13

V <- 1 / (1 + (C / H)^n) 
V_C <- V_max*V

x3 <- sapply(V_C, function(x) rnorm(100, x, 1))
means_x3 <- colMeans(x3)

y3 <- lapply(1:len_C, function(z) hist(x3[z], plot=FALSE,breaks=20))
# calculate checks using apply
check1 <- apply(x3, 2, function(x) sum(x < x1_right)) / 100
check2 <- apply(x3, 2, function(x) sum(x > x_right & x < x1_right)) / 100
```

If you check your Environment panel you will see that the scalars are expanded to vectors, a matrix (x3) and a list (y3).  To plot the y3 elements, reference each by its list index number. E.g.:

```
plot(y3[[1]], col='gray48',xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max)))
```

Comment: SteveM Thank you very much for your help, if I understand answer and how it works, It will give you the percentage of observations that meet the specified conditions for each histogram and I can do it even in the for loop (as I have it recommended in my task)

Comment: SteveM Could you please answer?

Comment: I assumed that `x3` are the observations that you are referring to.  The `x3` in your `for` loop is a single vector.  You could embed the checks as vectors in your loop without the apply function: 'check1[i] <- sum(x < x1_right)) / 100' check[i] would increment with each iteration.  Note that using explicit 'for' loops in R when you don't have to is not a good coding practice, because the code is more complex and 'for' loops can be much slower than the vectorized alternatives.